# Cannot insert special character to a List

Tags: python, string, list, append, literals

Hello I am trying to modify some list ex :

```
text = "charlie's angel"
textSplit = list(text)
textSplit.insert(6, "\")
print textSplit
```

when i try, it results error **'EOL While scanning literal'**. As i know that error is because something wrong with string (especially "\" character).

The desired result is "charlie\'s angel"

Any idea how to insert "\" to a list with insert()?

Comment: you dont have a list in this code

Comment: sorry, i had edit my question

Answer (score 1):

you need to escape the special meaning of backslash in string by using another backslash.

```
text = "charlie's angel"
textSplit = list(text)
textSplit.insert(7, "\\")
print(textSplit)
print("".join(textSplit))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['c', 'h', 'a', 'r', 'l', 'i', 'e', '\\', "'", 's', ' ', 'a', 'n', 'g', 'e', 'l']
charlie\'s angel
```

Comment: hi @Chris, although its been 2 year since this post, i would like to say thankyou for answering my question. :)

Comment: Thakyou brother..@alvin

Answer (score 1):

You can use it to input string at dynamic position.

```
text = "charlie's angel"
n = 6
print(text[:n+1] + "\\" + text[n+1:])
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
charlie\'s angel
```

Comment: hi @Shivam , i like your approach on using this dynamic position. thankyou for answering the question

Answer (score 0):

you can do `text[:6] + '\\' + text[6:]`

Best regard

Comment: This stil has the same issue

Comment: Instead of '\' its '\\'

Comment: thankyou @TOTO for the answer :)